# Python read first and second lines then second lines and third lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file like this:

Date Closed_Price

t    101

t+1  103.1

t+2  104

t+3  100

I want to calculate the return on day(t+1), day(t+2), day(t+3) ...

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line1, line2 in f:
        rate_return = (line2[Closed_Price] - line1[Closed_Price])/line1[Closed_Price]
    the next iteration should be line2, line3
```

Any one can help me? thanks a lot

Comment: is the data contained in an excel spreadsheet or a txt file?

Comment: @ dingo it is a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to store the current line for the next iteration of the `for` loop. On each iteration, you have access to the previous line *and* the current line. In the case of the first iteration, there is no previous line stored, so we skip the operation (inside of the `if` statement) that requires both lines.

```py
filename = "lines.txt"

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    previous_line = None
    for line in file:
        # strip trailing \r\n carriage return and newline character for this line
        line = line.rstrip()
        
        # skip the first line, as there is no previous line
        if previous_line is not None:
            print(previous_line, line, float(line) - float(previous_line))
            
        # store the current line into a variable, to use on the next iteration
        previous_line = line
```

With the file `lines.txt`:

```
101
103.1
104
100
```

The console output is:

```
101 103.1 2.0999999999999943
103.1 104 0.9000000000000057
104 100 -4.0
```

> Note: the awkward decimals are due to [floating point arithmetic precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html); your calculations will likely still be relatively accurate, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something simple like this where you have an iterator of 2.

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    f_lst = f.read().splitlines()
    
    for idx in range(0,len(s), 2):
        line1 = f_lst[idx] 
        line2 = f_lst[idx+1]
        rate_return = (line2[Closed_Price] - line1[Closed_Price])/line1[Closed_Price]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a CSV file you can read it into a pandas dataframe and do all the analysis there with the in-built functions

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=" ")
data['return'] = data['Closed_Price'].pct_change()
```