How to perform something like 'ordered_choice' replacement which returns a single text string when called similar to performance of 'random.choice'?
This question and code attempt is based mainly on the question asked here: random.choice() equivalent in order and here: Python read first and second lines then second lines and third lines
The ideal solution would be a 'drop in' code snippet let's call 'def ordered_choice' which reads each line from a text file, allows a python script to process it (as per random.choice), then moves on to next line and repeats the process until all text lines are read and processed in order when called.
random.choice of course works perfectly by returning a single line when called if a random line is the what's needed but I'm running into difficulties trying to iterate through a sorted text line-by-line to mimic this performance in an incremental and ordered manner.
1.random_choice.py works exactly as it should and this code can be dropped into other scripts including replace functions:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import os
    import random

    # 1. random.choice works as expected here and in other scripts without need for 'for l in range(0, 9):'

    for l in range(0, 9):

       def openFile(filepath):
          with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
              return infile.read()
    
       text_lines = openFile('sorted_text_strings.txt').splitlines()
       sentence = random.choice(text_lines)
       print(sentence)

2.iter_cycle.py returns the first line as specified but adding additional - print(next(sentence)) - returns 2 or more lines at once. Can this be modified to read the same text file and work with a counter?
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import os
    #import random
    import itertools
    from itertools import cycle

    # using iter.cycle

    # 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782991/random-choice-equivalent-in-order

    # Question: How to read text file 'sorted_text_strings.txt' and return each line in order when called in script similar to single line returned above with 'random.choice' ?

    sorted_text_strings = ['Alice went for a walk in the park.', 'Bob watched the football game with his friends.', 'Carol finished painting her kitchen.', 'Dave met his friends at their favorite bar.', 'Edele took her dog for a jog.', 'Frank waved to Alice in the park.', 'Gail met Dave and their friends at the bar.', 'Harry wondered what all his friends were doing.', 'etc.']

    sentence = iter(cycle(sorted_text_strings))
    print(next(sentence)) # line 1
    #print(next(sentence)) # line 2 etc. can't repeat this as it will return all lines during a single call. Missing a counter?
    

3.read_plus_range.py returns 1 or all lines depending on range value. Attempting to mimic similar 'def openFile(filepath):' used with random.choice:
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import os

    # 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130513/python-read-first-and-second-lines-then-second-lines-and-third-lines

    # Question: Attempting to edit above to work here. Can this be modified to accomplish task? Missing a counter?

    for l in range(0, 1):

       def openFile(filepath):
          with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
              return infile.read()

       text_lines = openFile('sorted_text_strings.txt').splitlines()       
       for idx in range(0, 9):
          sentence = text_lines[idx] # line 1 only IF for idx in range(0, 1):
    #      sentence = text_lines[idx+1] # line 2 only IF for idx in range(0, 1):
          print(sentence)   
    
    # for l in range(0, 10): repeated all 9 lines 10x - same as print() 10x entire file?

    # for l in range(0, 1):  repeated all 9 lines 1x - same as print() 1x of entire file?

'sorted_text_strings.txt' comprises 9 lines as follows:
    Alice went for a walk in the park.
    Bob watched the football game with his friends.
    Carol finished painting her kitchen.
    Dave met his friends at their favorite bar.
    Edele took her dog for a jog.
    Frank waved to Alice in the park.
    Gail met Dave and their friends at the bar.
    Harry wondered what all his friends were doing.
    etc.

My python skills (such as they are) are fully dependent on the professional abilities of others. I search for scripts and code blocks that I can modify to suit my needs and only post a question if I can't solve it based on my trial and error (mostly error) testing. It's been a while since I've posted.
Looking forward to learning something new here that will improve my scripts.
